# Parent view and controller reloaded on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent with a right-drawer view which is reloaded whenever I change the state. I am trying to prevent it from reloading.

This is the parent state

```
.state('main', {
    url: 'main',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.tpl.html',
            controller: 'mainController as vm'
        },
        'right-drawer@main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/right-drawer/right-drawer.tpl.html',
            controller: 'rightDrawerController as vm'
        }
    }
})
```

and a child state. I am trying to conditionally hide the right-drawer view away from main.customer when creating a new customer. However when I switch state with something like `$state.go('main.dashboard');` it then reloads the right-drawer... How can I keep it from reloading?

```
.state('main.customer', {
    url: '/customer',
    params: {
        company: null
    },
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/my-account/my-account.tpl.html',
            controller: 'myAccountController as vm'
        },
        'right-drawer@main': {
            templateProvider: function($stateParams, $templateFactory, userService) {
                return $stateParams.company !== 'NEW'
                    ? $templateFactory.fromUrl('app/main/right-drawer/right-drawer.tpl.html', $stateParams)
                    : null;
            },
            controllerProvider: function($stateParams, userService) {
                var ctrlName = $stateParams.company !== 'NEW'
                    ? 'rightDrawerController'
                    : '';
                return ctrlName;
            },
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }
})
```

I have tried calling the view in main.customer a `'right-drawer'` instead of `'right-drawer@main'` but that doesn't let me use the templateProvider and controllerProvider. I think it simply uses the right drawer from the main state. I have also tried `$state.go('main.dashboard', {}, {notify: false});` and `$state.go('main.dashboard', {}, {reload: false});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible for children to determine whether a [named view](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views#multiple-named-uiviews) is rendered in a parent. I know they can target that view and replace it with another controller/component, but that still won't help you I believe.

Perhaps the simplest way is to add a `ng-show` on the right-drawer in the `mainController` and use [`$state.is`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#is) to only render it on states which you want.

```js
// template.html

<ui-view name="right-drawer" ng-show="vm.shouldShowDrawer()"></ui-view>

// controller.js

$scope.shouldShowDrawer = function() {
    return $state.is('main') || $state.is('main.dashboard')
}
```

Comment: I would need a lot of these in the controller. That's why I was thinking of placing them in the $stateProvider for readability. You could easily look at each state and see why the view is or is not visible.